# Convert Pandas DataFrame to Dictionary using multiple columns for the key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame as below

```
From_email,To_email,email_count
110165.74@compuserve.com,klay@enron.com,1
2krayz@gte.net,klay@enron.com,1
"<""d@piassick"".@enron@enron.com>",klay@enron.com,1
```

I would like to change it to a dictionary of the following format

```
hrc_dict = {('110165.74@compuserve.com', 'klay@enron.com'): 1,
            ('2krayz@gte.net', 'klay@enron.com'): 1, 
            ('<"d@piassick".@enron@enron.com>', 'klay@enron.com '): 1}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`dict` comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to create the `dict` from your `DataFrame`.

```
df = DataFrame({
    'From_email': ['110165.74@compuserve.com', '2krayz@gte.net', '<"d@piassick".@enron@enron.com>'],
    'To_email': ['klay@enron.com', 'klay@enron.com', 'klay@enron.com'],
    'email_count': [1, 1, 1]})

d = {tuple(x[:2]):x[2] for x in df[['From_email', 'To_email', 'email_count']].values}
```

First we *explicitly* grab the necessary columns from your data frame in the desired order. Then iterate over the rows and for each row, create a tuple from the email addresses (first two columns) and use this as the key. The value is simply the 3rd column (`email_count`)

Comment: @AJV if this worked, please consider marking it an answer to help those who stumble upon this later.